# How do I require NPMJS elements in Sails JS

Tags: sails.js, handlebars.js

Please do point me to the docs if the answer is there, I couldn't see it.

I am used to requiring things in node, how do I do this in sails where you would normally

```
var handlebars-helpers    = require('diy-handlebars-helpers');
```

Comment: You do it exactly like that.

Comment: Did you get any error message?